# array.push seems to replace previous object rather than append

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas

I want to collect coordinates for rectangles I'm drawing across canvas area.  When I push the next set of coords into my array, each of the previous entries in the array become the new set, rather than remaining as their original coords.

I'm a one-week veteran of javascript so I'm pretty sure this is a newbie question. I'm replacing a small Excel VBA I wrote to demo an algebra concept for my students because not every student has Excel on their computer, and the online version of Excel doesn't run VBA macros.  I want a stand-alone app they can download and run offline.
I have no problem drawing the rectangles.  I want arr(ndx) to contain the coordinates of the ndx-th rectangle. Ultimately if a student selects a set of rectangles I will change the background color of that set.
My console output shows that on the ndx-th iteration, all the arr entries from 0 to ndx contain the same set of coordinates, the last one that was captured.
To me it looks like arr.push is over-writing each previous entry with the current one, rather than appending them to the array.  What am I missing?
I've gutted my code just to illustrate the problem I'm having. Included console.log code for last part of output block.

```
var arr = [];  var ndx = 0;   //array to contain rectangle coords  

Rows = 2; Cols = 3;           //Actual 40 X 60 or so.  
for (j=0; j<Rows;j++) {  
    for (i=0; i<Cols; i++) {  
        obj.row = j; obj.col = i;
        obj.xpos = obj.xpos + obj.xpos * j;     
        obj.ypos = obj.ypos + obj.ypos * i;  

        // will actually use fillRect() here to draw  
        //grid of rectangles spread across screen.  This works.  

        arr.push({obj});    // capture rect's coords for later reference  

        watchit0 = Object.entries(arr[ndx].obj);    //for debugging  
        if (ndx > 0) {  
            watchit1 = Object.entries(arr[ndx - 1].obj); }  
        else {  
            watchit1 = "                          ";  
        }  

        watchit2 = Object.keys(arr);    
        console.log("obj: " + Object.entries(obj)  
+ "     arr: " + watchit0 + "    arr-1: "  
+ watchit1 + "    keys: " + watchit2);

        ndx++;  
    }  
}  

//everything below is for debugging  
console.log("  ");  

watchit00 = Object.entries(arr[0].obj);  
watchit01 = Object.entries(arr[1].obj);  
watchit02 = Object.entries(arr[2].obj);  
watchit03 = Object.entries(arr[3].obj);  
watchit04 = Object.entries(arr[4].obj);  
watchit05 = Object.entries(arr[5].obj);  

console.log("     0: " + watchit00 + "     1:  " + watchit01);  
console.log("     2: " + watchit02 + "     3:  " + watchit03);  
console.log("     4: " + watchit04 + "     5:  " + watchit05);
```

`console.log` output (reformatted):

```
obj: row,0,col,0,xpos,1,ypos,10       
arr: row,0,col,0,xpos,1,ypos,10       arr-1:                                                       keys: 0

obj: row,0,col,1,xpos,1,ypos,20       
arr: row,0,col,1,xpos,1,ypos,20       arr-1: row,0,col,1,xpos,1,ypos,20       keys: 0,1

obj: row,0,col,2,xpos,1,ypos,60       
arr: row,0,col,2,xpos,1,ypos,60       arr-1: row,0,col,2,xpos,1,ypos,60       keys: 0,1,2

obj: row,1,col,0,xpos,2,ypos,60       
arr: row,1,col,0,xpos,2,ypos,60       arr-1: row,1,col,0,xpos,2,ypos,60       keys: 0,1,2,3

obj: row,1,col,1,xpos,4,ypos,120     
arr: row,1,col,1,xpos,4,ypos,120     arr-1: row,1,col,1,xpos,4,ypos,120    keys: 0,1,2,3,4

obj: row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     
arr: row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     arr-1: row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360    keys: 0,1,2,3,4,5
```

What's below is output `arr[ndx]` at the end of my code.
I'm expecting the 6 entries to match obj: above but every entry is the last iteration. Why??

```
0:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     
1:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     
2:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     
3:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360   
4:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360     
5:  row,1,col,2,xpos,8,ypos,360
```

Comment: have you considered formatting your code - indentation makes code actually readable

Comment: If looks like you are reusing the same `obj` in every loop (but it doesn't seem to be defined anywhere in your sample code so it's hard to be sure).

Comment: I just spent 3+ hours trying to format my code to get this question to accept it.  I'm open to suggestions.  Used Komodo ide auto formatter to finally get it here.  I've formatted it every way I can think of.

Comment: Sorry - I left that line out of my copy.  var obj = {row: 22, col: 33, xpos: 1, ypos: 10};

Comment: @Mark - when I look at my output, obj changes on each loop, and arr(ndx) shows the new values.  But then arr(ndx - 1) also shows the new values, rather than what it showed on the previous pass.  How can that be?  In my mind, arr(ndx - 1) is set in stone once the ndx step begins, unless I specifically change arr(ndx - 1) at some point in the future.  Isn't obj just holding my data until I store it in arr(ndx)?  How can arr.push go back and change arr(ndx - 1)? Obviously I'm missing something.  How should I be handling obj?

Comment: Add `Object.create(obj); ` at the start of each for iterations. `obj` is by `ref` not `value` and so you are simply adding and changing properties on the same `Object` the create will solve this for you.

Comment: When you push into the array, you just push a reference to the object not a copy of the object. Since you push the same object everything you push is referencing the same object. Change the object and everything in the array get's changed. You need to copy the object fresh in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here Steve. 
The first code shows a simplified version of where you are going wrong. 
NOTE: if you were to do a test, each object in the Array would be the same object.

The second shot at the code shows using Object.create on our object function to get a new instance.

Hope this helps.

```js
let sampleArrValues = [1,2,3,4,5];

function myObject(num) {
  this.number = num;
}
console.log('Bad Array Demo');
// This wont work
let badArray = [];
var obj = new myObject(1);

sampleArrValues.forEach(num => {
  obj.number = num;
  badArray.push(obj);
});

// Lets look at the array content
badArray.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.number);
});
// -> 5,5,5,5,5


console.log('Good Array Demo');
// Now do properly
var goodArray = [];

sampleArrValues.forEach(num => {
  obj = Object.create(myObject);
  obj.number = num;
  goodArray.push(obj);
});

goodArray.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.number);
});
// -> 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Thank you!  My test code works (you knew it would!)  I still have to digest what I'm seeing but at least I can make it work.  Thanks for a clear explanation of what doesn't work and what does.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt on the answers you already got:

- first part of the snippet shows what you have, but usually you do not want: a single object is stored in the `obj1` variable at the beginning, and it gets `push`-ed into `arr1` after setting `x` to a different value. The log lines in the console show that the `push` itself happens properly (the array grows), but as the same object is stored multiple times, the growing amount of content all shows the last value set via `obj1.x`
- second part of the snippet shows what you should do: it is very similar, but it initializes `obj2` with a whole new object in each iteration, and thus not only the number of elements in the array grows, but they are also referring different objects with different content.

```js
var obj1={x:1,
          toString:function(){return this.x;}};
var arr1=[];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  obj1.x=i;
  arr1.push(obj1);
  console.log(arr1.join());
}

console.log("---");

var arr2=[];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  var obj2={x:i,
            toString:function(){return this.x;}};
  arr2.push(obj2);
  console.log(arr2.join());
}
```

Side note: in the original code, `arr.push({obj});` is used, which does create a new object (it is a shorthand for `arr.push({obj:obj});`), the `obj` field of the newly created object always refer to the same, single object you have stored in `obj` somewhere at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I'll digest your code, which came while I was implementing Paul's answer.

Comment: @SteveHarris the main difference is the `Object.create()` vs. simple `{}`. Both of them creates a brand new, independent object, and that is the key part here. On top of that, `Object.create()` creates a copy of the original object, which includes possible extra stuff, like prototype, or fields what you want to keep, but do not want to set again. Here this kind of extra stuff simply do not exist, there are 3 fields, and there is a new value for each, that is why I do not feel the need of creating a copy of the original.

Comment: (And the `toString()` part is only there for providing the numbers as output, instead of `[object Object]` or something similar. Actually this is something which could be preserved via `Object.create()`, just here it not really part of the intended example, it is needed for the logging only)